Airflow how to run a bash script from on_failure_callback custom function
I want to create a function which will be released on_failure_callback.
It has to start a script on the server on which Airflow is installed.
Any tips how to do it?

Since I know nothing of your existing Code (I guess there isn't one) I can only give you general advice:

paramiko SSH client is solid to connect via SSH

exec_command: To run stuff on your remote machine/server

Call the Method via Errorhandling. So if stuff breaks catch it and run your method.

check if you have the permissions to run stuff on the machine


logging and integrating to the DAG may be good practice aswell depending on the case
Consider Retries if they fit your case

Actually it was quite simple. I used Pythons
subprocess.run("touch foo", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
